# Prevent sorting from being switched to Date Modified every time the site is visited

Tags: bug, sorting

Whenever I open Stack Overflow or any new page, the sorting gets reset to "Date Modified (Newest First)". I want it to be "Highest Score" by default. Even if I switch back to that (which says default), when I open any new page it's again Date Modified.

Here's a GIF image demonstrating the issue (the quality is due to a 2 MB file size limit):

[image]

I'm on Safari 15.6.1 on Mac.

Comment: Somehow cannot repro on Chrome 105, Mac 12.2. The sorting option is preserved across questions. After pressing "Reset to default", the page will be redirected to the same page with `answertab=scoredesc#tab-top` added. This will set the sort to "Highest score", and normally it should preserve across other questions.

Comment: @AndrewT. that's what I thought it should be too. But for some reason, it doesn't persist on me.

Comment: For searching existing meta question, what is the terminology for the sticky feature (it doesn't seem to be "sticky", though Atwood [and others](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10923/eliminate-sticky-tabs) used that word in the early days)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I don't think I'm following. What exactly were you asking?